# Python re- match if not substring

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to construct a regular expression, which matches if the string starts with
'Isaac' but does not match if there is somewhere 'Asimov' in it i.e.:

```
"Isaac Peter bla hello" -> match
"Isaac Peter bla Asimov hello" -> no match
```

My attempt was:

```
Isaac.*?(?!Asimov)
```

which fails so that my regex always matches (I don't know why) 
Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by *fails*?

Comment: this case is not appropriate for `regex`. can be easily done with string.

Comment: By fails I mean it matches everything

Comment: I got a module which identifies lines by regex, so this case is appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like below.

```
^Isaac(?!.*?Asimov).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kO1pA3/3)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """Isaac Peter bla hello
... Isaac Peter bla Asimov hello"""
>>> re.findall(r'(?m)^Isaac(?!.*?Asimov).*$', s)
['Isaac Peter bla hello']
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
Isaac                    'Isaac'
(?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                           times)
  Asimov                   'Asimov'
)                        end of look-ahead
.*                       any character except \n (0 or more times)
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes i'm a blockhead :)

Comment: Do we really need a lookahead for that? Is it faster or is my simple solution similar?

Comment: @wenzul Your solution does not provide what i need: Your solution is inverse to what i need and i have no choice to invert the regex, if you are interested in background, have a look here:
http://docs.ansible.com/lineinfile_module.html
This module replaces a line by regex occurence, with no option for inverse etc.

Comment: @ProfHase85 Sure, but where is the problem to do a `if not re.match...`? You just need to differentiate and can negate that?

Comment: @wenzul I'm not in source code, I just pass the regex to an external module

Comment: @ProfHase85 Ok, this was not obvious in your desciption because it's just tagged with _python_.

Answer (score 1):

Or, without regex:

```
if str.startswith('Isaac') and 'Asimov' not in str:
    # ...
```

Comment: I need a regex (for ansible module ;) )

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to match and don't want to have groups you can use

```
import re
>>> a="Isaac Peter bla hello"
>>> b="Isaac Peter bla Asimov hello"
>>> re.match(r"^Isaac.*Asimov.*$", a)
>>> re.match(r"^Isaac.*Asimov.*$", b)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001D4E9F0>
```

You can easily invert the match...